# Borrar documentos automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

actualmente me ha surgido una duda, tengo un pequeño servidor el cual subo documentos mediante un formulario, este al ser subido, queda el registro de la hora el cual ha sido subido y cuando debería ser borrado, me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera sencilla de que se borre el archivo siguiendo la mecánica de utilizar php o js (la base de datos es de mysql sobre linux server).

Comment: Podrías hacer un cron que lance el php para borrar periódicamente.

Comment: @track3r Gracias, es lo mas viable que he encontrado de momento

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede mediante php puedes obtener el día actual del servidor con la función 
`date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`, al obtener el día actual del servidor haces un **delete**

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE columna_fecha_borrar = Variable_obtenida
```

donde `columna_fecha_borrar` es el campo de la base de datos y la variable obtenida es la que contiene la fecha y hora capturada del servidor

claro falta hacer una conexión del código php a la base de datos

aquí te dejo un link para borrar un archivo de MySql

[Link: php_mysql_delete](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp)

Comment: No digo el registro de sql, el registro ya se borra automaticamente pero queda el documento fisico

Comment: ok si quieres eliminar el archivo tienes que usar unlink('ruta del archivo']); asi eliminas un archivo del servidor, aqui te mando un link para usar unlink http://php.net/manual/es/function.unlink.php